# Storing a complex Query within MongoDb Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm looking to store a Mongo query within a Document, and later pull that query and execute it. Something like this would allow me to have customizable dashboards for users.

But I can't store the query within a document because field names cannot contain/start with `$`

Is there any way to do such a thing as I've described?

Example Query:

```
{
  sectionA:
    {
      fieldA: valA,
      fieldB: valB,
      fieldC: valC
    },
  sectionB:
    {
      fieldD: { $in : ["A", "B", "C"] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wound up coming to the same solution as the first answer on my own about 5 minutes ago. I did run a bunch of searches on SO, but found nothing quite like this. Thanks a bunch,